# How to average Total column based on the orders that have a combination of two specific products in the order

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to add a formula that will average the total column based on the orders that have a specific combination of products bought together. I've tried several different formulas with no luck. I'd like it to be dynamic and based on product descriptions in cells J2:K6.  Ideally, for each order that has the combination of products, I'd like to either sum or average the total column (column H).

[updated example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ8zq.png)
[spreadsheetexample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0jkw.png)

Comment: What formulas have you tried?

Comment: For example, in the seventh row, do you need to ask for the average value of product A plus E? Then average each row in turn?

Comment: This formula worked for when I needed it to do just a simple count of the # of orders that contained the two products.  But it doesn't work for summing or averaging the $.  =IF($B4=$C4,"NA",SUM(INDIRECT("table3["&$B4&"]")*INDIRECT("table3["&$C4&"]")))

Comment: So I tried these two and they didn't work:  =SUMPRODUCT(('Table5'1:1='Item Impact'!B4)*('Table5'!1:1='Item Impact'!C4)*('Table5'!CA:CA))}   and this:  =SUM(IF('multi items TABLE Item Price'!1:1='Item Impact'!B4,IF('multi items TABLE Item Price'!1:1='Item Impact'!C4,'multi items TABLE Item Price'!CA:CA)))

Comment: I'm looking to average the Total column #'s based on if they have two products in their basket.  So I'm looking to average all the #'s in orange.  So even if there's a 3rd or 4th item in the basket with the two products, I would still want the average of the totals.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1751455/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Answer (score 0):

Say the headers begin in A1 and the last total is in H20, so the highlighted in yellow cells are in columns B and F, then use:

```
=AVERAGE(  FILTER(H2:H20,  (B2:B20<>0) * (F2:F20<>0)  )  )
```

`FILTER` will collect the rows that meet the conditions. Those conditions are in the second half, one being that the cells with non-zero values qualify as it would seem those are the ones with the product in the basket, with columns B and F being checked. Each test produces an array of TRUE/FALSE results which, because of the multiplication of the two arrays, causes Excel to coerce into 1/0's instead. So when both tests are TRUE, you get 1*1=1 and for the three other possibilities, you get zero times something (1 or 0) so that equals 0.

`FILTER then keeps all the rows that resulted in 1. The trick is that you are just asking it to return the cell from each successful row that is in the Total column, column H.

Armed then with all, and only all, the totals that qualify, `AVERAGE` gets your desired final result.

Notice you need to enclose EACH test in its own set of parentheses. Without them, Excel will surely misunderstand how the arithmetic is supposed to happen.

More complicated versions can be set up with multiplication being AND and addition being OR. You just need to keep individual tests inside their own sets of parentheses and to use parentheses to keep groups of results together.